# how to connect to azure PaaS postgres from on-prem

Tags: postgresql, azure

General infrastructure artchitecture/best practice: Developing locally against and azure hosted postgres

I've created an infrastructure on azure using terraform that is the following:

1. public virtual network (vn)
2. two subnets associated with the vn, one for my Postgres flexible server, and for a vm/app server that will host a web-based data service to r/w from the database
3. the Postgres server is setup using azurerm_private_dns_zone
   While i can ssh into the vm to do my work, its purpose is really as a 'prod/uat' environment to deploy code to.

Instead, i would like to be able to continue developing on my local system and connect to that azure Postgres.   The problem is its private.
From what i read if you make the Postgres server public, you have to enable access by ip (which is great), but it is put on a separate virtual network.  So, my questions are..

1. is there any way to have the  public Postgres server on the same virtual network as my app server to reduce latency? or is my concern about latency not warranted?
2. is there an option here to keep it private, but be able to connect from my local dev workstation without having to remote into saw the app server to get to it?
3. the third question is somewhat different - my local setup current is i run everything in docker containers locally, including Postgres.  im wondering if i should not simply do the same for the integrated environment - running everything in two containers on the same App server?  What is the general best practice around this kind of setup and how are most folks doing this today?  managed db or containers all the way?

Any thoughts on this appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

1. Traffic inside Azure is generally very performant and is rarely a bottleneck, especially in an average web application. If you have a very, very transaction-heavy application, you might want to explore some other options.
2. By setting up a VPN. For single use cases, [a point-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) could do the trick, however, usually organizations centralize this and have an [Express Route](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/expressroute) or a [site-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal). For a hobbyist, trying out some more modern solutions like [TailScale](https://tailscale.com/) could be an option.
   Alternatively, you could change the networking mode to "Public" and only allow the public IP of your VM and your local IP to access it. However, this means the traffic goes over the public interfaces and the end result is less secure.
3. Managing your database by yourself is certainly possible, however, the management overhead will be significantly higher. Also, you generally do not want to run the application and the database on the same server, except in development situations. If you do not have experience in running databases, I would not recommend that option.

Finally: is it mandatory to use the Azure Postgres in development? Quite often development environments are self-contained (meaning you run your DB and app both in docker) and the managed stuff only kicks in Test/QA/Prod environments. This grants developers more freedom to mess around with the database and develop offline or with a bad connection, while the testing / QA steps will catch problems that might be caused by the slight differences in a managed database compared to a dockerized, local database.

Comment: thanks for the response.  for now im doing exactly that..app and postgres run locally in separate containers.  there is now a need for more collaborative development (front/mid/backend) - so i need an integrated end point which developers can connect to from their home setup.  
been readong about P2S  and S2S, but have not heard come across any success stories w/ regards to postgres on a private cloud dns.  So for now i may go with the public option
thanks much for your detailed response - appreciate it.